# LINQ and the KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to count items in a group. So I have this LINQ to Entities query:

```
var qry2 = from c in qry
           group c by c.Content.DownloadType into grouped
           select new KeyValuePair(grouped.Key,grouped.Count());
```

But it doesn't work because LINQ to Entities only accepts parameter initializers or parameterless constructors. So I created a simple class to envelop the KeyValuePair type:

```
public class ValueCount
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public KeyValuePair<string, int> ToKeyValuePair()
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, int>(this.Key, this.Value);
    }
}
```

And changed the query to:

```
var qry2 = from c in qry
           group c by c.Content.DownloadType into grouped
           select new ValueCount
           {
               Key = grouped.Key,
               Value = grouped.Count()
           }.ToKeyValuePair();
```

But still doesn't work. It says that it doesn't recognizes the method ToKeyValuePair()

How can I collect KeyValuePairs from a LINQ to Entities query?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with Linq to Entities is that it can only do things that the database knows how to do.  It can convert to your ValueCount type after the fact, but as soon as you call the ToKeyValuePair() method, Linq to Entities gives up, because it doesn't know what to do with it.  As the answers below mention, call AsEnumerable() or ToList() to force the IEnumerable to iterate (forcing the DB call), then make your conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `AsEnumerable()` to isolate your code from EF's:

```
var qry2 = from c in qry
    group c by c.Content.DownloadType into grouped
    select new ValueCount
    {
        Key = grouped.Key,
        Value = grouped.Count()
    }.AsEnumerable()   // This "cuts off" your method from the Entity Framework,
    .Select(vc => vc.ToKeyValuePair()); // letting you nicely complete the conversion in memory
```

Comment: Thanks, but the .ToKeyValuePair is a method of ValueCount, not of IEnumerable<ValueCount>

Answer (score 5):

You have to call your method once you have the results back from the db and you can do that by forcing the query using ToList() and then doing a select to call your method on each item.

```
   (from c in qry
   group c by c.Content.DownloadType into grouped
   select new ValueCount
   {
       Key = grouped.Key,
       Value = grouped.Count()
   }).ToList().Select(x=>x.ToKeyValuePair());
```

Like Eric rightly says in the comments you can get rid of your custom class and do something like

```
   (from c in qry
   group c by c.Content.DownloadType into grouped
   select new
   {
       Key = grouped.Key,
       Value = grouped.Count()
   }).ToList().Select(x=>new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x.Key, x.Value));
```

Comment: It seems like the ValueCount class is no longer necessary. Just use an anonymous type and get rid of the extra code.

Comment: Thanks, this works. @Eric, how would be to get rid of the ValueCount class? How can I convert the anonymous type to a KeyValuePair or Dictionary, whatever?